# How to hide kendo Tooltip appear in detailInit (child grid)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had a similar grid as this example. In this grid I create tooltip at "First Name" column where the condition meet. But when I open the sub grid, the tooltip also appear in the first row of sub child (example image).. Any idea how to hide it?

Here are the [demo in DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/UBatAGUZ)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could adjust the filter option of the tooltip to target only the first-level of the grid:

```
filter: ".k-grid-content > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)",
```

Here is the modified Dojo

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/IZIvIxUg)